# Python: mimic the effect of groupby with list/dict comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need to transform a list of dict:

```
original = [
    {'type': 'a', 'length': 34, 'width': 74},
    {'type': 'a', 'length': 15, 'width': 22},
    {'type': 'b', 'length': 53, 'width': 54},
    {'type': 'b', 'length': 11, 'width': 45},
]
```

into a dict with the value of `type` key as the key:

```
expected = {
    'a': [
        {'type': 'a', 'length': 34, 'width': 74},
        {'type': 'a', 'length': 15, 'width': 22},
    ],
    'b': [
        {'type': 'b', 'length': 53, 'width': 54},
        {'type': 'b', 'length': 11, 'width': 45},
    ],
}
```

This can be achieved with `itertools.groupby` or by iterating through the list manually, but is there any way to do it with just list/dict comprehension?

Comment: That is a strange combination of restrictions. Why these?

Comment: You can use collections module also.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I was hoping for an one-liner that is still easy to read and understand, but it seems that it will introduce some pointless complexity into the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
{t: [i for i in original if i['type'] == t] for t in {i['type'] for i in original}}
```

But it's both difficult to read and has a worst-case runtime complexity of *O(n²)*, where *n* is the number of items in the list. Using `itertools.groupby` on a sorted list is both faster and easier to read.

Comment: I haven't thought of using the second collection `{i['type'] for i in original}` yet, it's a nice idea, though you are right, it adds some pointless complexity.